# How to view two rows with the same cell entry?

Tags: r

I have three columns `title`, `lat` and `long` in a df `sure`. All the variables are of character class. I want to see which entries in the `title` column have the same `lat` or `long`. How do I visualize this?

Comment: Have you tried `sure$title[sure$lat==sure$long]` ?  If you want to see the explicit rows, you may use `sure[sure$lat==sure$long,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `filter()` for all values which have `lat == long` and then `select()` the title. Here is a small example:

```
library(tidyverse)

sure <- tibble(
    title = c("ti1", "ti2", "ti3", "ti4"),
    lat = c("la", "lb", "lc", "ld"),
    long = c("la", "le", "lf", "ld")
)

sure |> filter(lat == long) |>
    select(title)

# A tibble: 2 × 1
  title
  <chr>
1 ti1  
2 ti4
```